# python-requests with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I am working on creating a HTTP client which can generate hundreds of connections each second and send up to 10 requests on each of those connections. I am using threading so concurrency can be achieved.
Here is my code:

```
def generate_req(reqSession):
    requestCounter = 0
    while requestCounter < requestRate:
        try:
            response1 = reqSession.get('http://20.20.1.2/tempurl.html')
            if response1.status_code == 200:
                client_notify('r')
        except(exceptions.ConnectionError, exceptions.HTTPError, exceptions.Timeout) as Err:
            client_notify('F')
            break
        requestCounter += 1

def main():
    for q in range(connectionPerSec):
        s1 = requests.session()
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=generate_req, args=(s1,))
        t1.start()
```

Issues:

1. It is not scaling above 200 connections/sec with requestRate = 1. I ran other available HTTP clients on the same client machine and against the server, test runs fine and it is able to scale.
2. When requestRate = 10, connections/sec drops to 30.
   Reason: Not able to create targeted number of threads every second.

For issue #2, client machine is not able to create enough request sessions and start new threads. As soon as requestRate is set to more than 1, things start to fall apart.
I am suspecting it has something to do with HTTP connection pooling which requests uses.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Why are you reusing the same `session` object? As I can understand, your `connectionPerSec` actually means the number of parallel threads, and `requestRate` is actually the number of serial requests on each thread. You might also want to look at [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html).

Comment: session object is reused only in the spawned thread so it uses the same connection for all serial requests.

Comment: Seems like ThreadPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures does the same thing what I am trying to do?

Comment: Note that in CPython the concurrency of threads is limited: Only one thread at a time can execute Python bytecode. This limitation is enforced by the Global Interpreter Lock to simplify memory management.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get things to fall apart, however the following code has some new features:

1) extended logging, including specific per-thread information

2) all threads `join()`ed at the end to make sure the parent process doesntt leave them hanging

3) multithreaded `print` tends to interleave the messages, which can be unwieldy. This version uses `yield` so a future version can accept the messages and print them clearly.

### source

```
import exceptions, requests, threading, time

requestRate = 1
connectionPerSec = 2


def client_notify(msg):
    return time.time(), threading.current_thread().name, msg

def generate_req(reqSession):
    requestCounter = 0
    while requestCounter < requestRate:
        try:
            response1 = reqSession.get('http://127.0.0.1/')
            if response1.status_code == 200:
                print client_notify('r')
        except (exceptions.ConnectionError, exceptions.HTTPError, exceptions.Timeout):
            print client_notify('F')
            break
        requestCounter += 1

def main():
    for cnum in range(connectionPerSec):
        s1 = requests.session()
        th = threading.Thread(
            target=generate_req, args=(s1,),
            name='thread-{:03d}'.format(cnum),
        )
        th.start()

    for th in threading.enumerate():
        if th != threading.current_thread():
            th.join()


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

### output

```
(1407275951.954147, 'thread-000', 'r')
(1407275951.95479, 'thread-001', 'r')
```