# How to parse multiple websites at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing, spyder

Using Python3, I wish to gather specific data from source codes from over 4000 web pages and export it to a csv format file.

Currently using:`urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")` along with `.split()` function,  along with DataFrames.

- I have run 6 kernels on Spyder at the same time with different url sets to increase the speed. Does this work?
- Can using multiprocessing work? Maybe executing 100 of those source code fetch jobs (pardon for lack of better terminology) at a time. Would that create a problem due to the traffic created on the website?
- I have been told that the TCP handshake time might be the bottleneck in this case. Any workarounds for the same?

What are other good/better ways to implement this using Python?
My current time estimate to completion I believe is about 60 hours, running only single kernel.

Comment: threading would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146901/python-requests-with-multithreading

Comment: Is there a limit to how many connections i can establish at once to a website to gather its data?